# How append to objects by using useState for infinite scrolling pagination?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

I'm currently trying to implement an infinite scrolling pagination feature with the `useState` hook to fetch the next 30 items (objects). The `useEffect` seen below fetches the first 30 items and sets that to the current state successfully on the web page. However when my `fetchMoreListItems()` is called to pull the next set of 30 once i've scrolled to the bottom, it doesn't append it to the previous 30 items, instead, the page refreshes and `setItems` within my `fetchMoreListItems()` function completely replaces the previous objects with the next ones. I'm trying to find a way to connect the previous state by appending the updated state. Is there a way to go about this? My attempt is seen below:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<Resource<Activities>[]>();
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.resource) return;
    props.resource
      .follow('activities-collection').followAll('item')
      .then(resources => {
        // this sets the first 30 objects to be displayed
        setItems(resources);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Error fetching resources: ' + err));
  }, [activityResource]);

  function fetchMoreListItems() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!props.resource) return;
      props.resource
        .follow('activities-collection').follow('next').followAll('item')
        .then(resources => {
         // I would like to append these new objects instead of replacing old ones
          setItems(resources);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('Error fetching resources: ' + err));
      setIsFetching(false);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nice ES6 feature for that.

`setItems([...items, ...resources])`

But I'd also recommend no rebuilding the wheel. [React Quer](https://react-query.tanstack.com/)y makes this extremely simple and hides all the ugliness

Answer (score 1):

How about just setting the state with the two arrays concatenated?

```
function fetchMoreListItems() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!props.resource) return;
    props.resource
      .follow('activities-collection').follow('next').followAll('item')
      .then(resources => {
         setItems(items.concat(resources));
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Error fetching resources: ' + err));
    setIsFetching(false);
  }, 1000);
}
```